# How to make printer added through CUPS show up in the default printer list on Centos

Tags: centos, printing, cups

I have added a network printer with cups, I can send a test print page through the cups web interface. However the printer won't show up in the default printer menus (i.e. when you press through Firefox -> Print) it just won't show up.

Is there anything specific thing you need to do to make the printer show up in the normal print menu for other applications?

Comment: Obvious question, but you did try restarting Firefox, right? Install `gtklp` if you don't have it installed already, and see if the printer shows up there.